# Error adding columns to personal view

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

One of our users is experiencing problems creating their own personal views in CRM 2011. They are able to get to the advanced find menu but as soon as they go to edit the columns a message appears simply stating that an error has occurred. They are however able to save the view with the default columns with no problem.

We have done a bit of testing and found that when we move the user from the default business unit to one we have created ourselves it works fine, and if we keep the user in the default business unit but give them admin rights it also works fine.

So it appears that it would be some kind of security/permissions issue, but i'm not sure on the next place to check. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out the cause of the problem.

It was a permissions issue after all. It turns out that in order to create personal views and edit the columns, the role assigned to the user must be given the ability to read customisations. Once this was done the problem went away.

And it was fixed when moving business units as the default team for those units had roles assigned to them that already had this privilege assigned.

Hopefully this might help someone with any similar issues